# Where is my mistake in the wp_enqueue_script?

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-5, wp-enqueue-scripts

I'm doing a portfolio. I didn't want to loose a lot of time but as newbie this is still difficult for me so i challenge myslef. So i took a template bootstrap and I want to 'import' the template on my wordpress website.

I used the wp_enqueue_script to link my css and js to my page. Here the code in the function.php :

```
unction portoflio_theme_bootstrap_scripts() {

wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css', array());
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-icons', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/vendor/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.css', array());
wp_enqueue_style( 'boxicons', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/vendor/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css', array());
wp_enqueue_style( 'glightbox', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/vendor/glightbox/css/glightbox.min.css', array());
wp_enqueue_style( 'swiper', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css', array());
wp_enqueue_style( 'main-style', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/style.css', array());

    wp_enqueue_script( 'purecounter', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/vendor/purecounter/purecounter_vanilla.js', array());
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array());
    wp_enqueue_script( 'glightbox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/vendor/glightbox/js/glightbox.min.js', array());
    wp_enqueue_script( 'isotope-layout', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/vendor/isotope-layout/isotope.pkgd.min.js', array());
    wp_enqueue_script( 'swiper', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js', array());
    wp_enqueue_script( 'waypoints', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/vendor/waypoints/noframework.waypoints.js', array());
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/main.js', array());


    }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'portoflio_theme_bootstrap_scripts' );
```

The css is working but the js not really. I think the js "isotope-layout" is woking because without this file, the section porfolio doesn't work. So, if this js file work, why the others don't work ?
I did a mistake somewhere.

Here the link of my one-page portoflio : https://pierre-fayard.com/visual-composer-3615/

I searched and tried a lot of things but nothing is working.
If you need more files, tell me. I'm a newbie so maybe i forgot something.

Thank you !

Comment: Look at your browser devtools, specifically the console and network tabs, to troubleshoot this sort of thing. You have some missing jpg files and a missing style.css.

Comment: Would be nice if you closed your issue after finding a solution. Looking at your link, seems like it's working now.

Comment: I looked in the devtools, i fixed the missing style.css, but I don't understand why the jpg don't show up. 
@Sun Nope, indeed this isn't working, I tried to add the scripts directly in the footer without passing by function.php but 1. this is not the good answer according what I find on the web and 2.this is not really solving the problem because I still have some problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it without having to mess up `function.php`.

Download and install [this plugin](https://github.com/srikat/my-custom-functionality).

Using FTP connection or using [File Manager plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-file-manager/), upload the JS and CSS files accordingly inside the `assets` folders.

Then, modify `plugin.php` by adding the JS and CSS enqueue codes inside `function custom_enqueue_files()` following the sample code format provided.

Comment: The probleme is solved, I forgot the stackoverflow forum, do you know how can I close the discussion ? 
My scripts were called in the header so it was a mess.
I used a fuction to call all the scripts in the footer and it works !

Comment: You can get info about how to close your question here -> https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96283/1033315